# Inspect return value without assign it to a variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have following code snipped:

```
...
var tpc = new ThirtPartyClass();

tpc.ExecuteCommand();
tpc.ExecuteCommand();
...
```

The ExecuteCommand() method returns a int value with some information. 
For debugging, I want to know this return values. But I don't want to assign the result to a variable (var result = tpc.ExecuteCommand()).

Is there in VisualStudio 2010 a possibility during debugging, to inspect this return value without assign it to a temporary variable?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

edit: Finally, this function has been added to [VS2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with IntelliTrace in VS2010, by switching to the "Calls View" then checking the Autos window:

[image]

But even without that, don't worry about it; if you don't use the variable (except by looking in the debugger when paused), then in a release build it will be removed and replaced with just a "pop" (which is what you get if you don't catch the return value in the first place).

So:

```
static void Main()
{
    int i = SomeMethod();
}
```

Compiles as:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: call int32 Program::SomeMethod()
    L_0005: pop 
    L_0006: ret 
}
```

note no `.locals` and no `stloc`.

For Resharper, use:

```
// ReSharper disable UnusedVariable
    int i = SomeMethod();
// ReSharper restore UnusedVariable
```

Comment: :-) you are right. My only problem is, that resharper dont likes this kind of code with 'local variable is never used'. And i dont want to suppress this kind of warning, because in much cases it helps...

Comment: So many times I've not had it assigned to something and wished it had been before I started debugging. Would be nice if it appeared with local variables or something.

Comment: @rhe1980 I wonder if r# has a "don't apply this **here**" option... edit: it does - see edit

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for your posts! I will try intellitrace. with suppress resharper warnings im a bit discreet because i dont want that finaly all in my team are using this and the code is full of suppressions :-)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks for the update (shame I use express though).

Comment: @MarcGravell: I tried intellitrace and i think it's what i searched! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a watch or use the immediate window during debugging. You can copy code into the immediate window to run it during debugging to see what it returns. It will execute the code again to get the return value, however.

Comment: Just to add to this, doing it this way assumes the method being called is idempotent. Be mindful of possible side effects of the extra call too.