# How do you determine the value of a return statement that isn't stored in a variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

The code I am working with has many recursive method calls that return the results of the method directly without storing it into a variable.

```
public bool foo()
{
  return bar();
}

public bool bar()
{
  return infinitMethodCalls();
}
```

As a result, debugging is a pain. How can I determine the value returned by bar() without using a temp variable or following the endless method calls?

temp variable example:

```
public bool foo()
{
  return result = bar();
}
```

The code I am working with is mostly written this way.

Comment: What version of VS? If it has intellitrace (in options -> intellitrace) then enable collection and it will dump the [return value] in the Autos window if you hit a breakpoint after the call and click the "Up" button in the gutter

Comment: I have VS2010 Pro and it doesn't have Intellitrace.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the version of VS you are using.

For Visual Studio 2013 you can show the "Autos" window, it dynamically displays all return values of functions you step over while debugging. You can find the Autos Window here: Debug => Windows => Autos in your VS Menu. (For more info see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx))

For Visual Studio 2010 for example you can use IntelliTraces "Calls View" as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893876/inspect-return-value-without-assign-it-to-a-variable)

Comment: Unfortunately, IntelliTrace is only available in VS Ultimate and I have VS2010 Pro.

Answer (score -1):

What about using a trace statement.  I'm assuming you want to know what the result of each call on the call stack is when debugging the recursion.

Note: Having the trace statement at the top of the function will order the output, to the console, from first to last.

For example:

```
void Factorial(int n) {

    Trace.WriteLine(n);

    if (n == 0)
       return 1;
    else
       return (n * factorial(n-1));

}
```

Comment: -1 Pretty sure the OP wanted to know how to do this without adding in additional code.

Comment: @gleng - the criteria said no temp variables nothing about adding code profiling technique.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention the code you posted won't compile.